# List<List<T>> sent to Func as parameter in parallel and Func executed multiple times results in some of the lists being duplicated and others skipped

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

We have a method `Execute` that gets called in parallel like so

```
    ListOfLists.Select(ids => Observable.FromAsync(() => Execute(request, ids))).Merge(10);
```

And we have

```
    protected Task<string> Execute(HttpRequestType request, IEnumerable<TItem> ids)
    {
        return SomeFunction(() => CreateRequest(request, ids.ToList()));
    }
```

CreateRequest(request, ids.ToList()) returns a `HttpRequestMessage` and `SomeFunction` takes a `Func<HttpRequestMessage>`.

And

```
    private async Task<T> SomeFunction(Func<HttpRequestMessage> func)
    {
        var request = func();
        var retryCount = 0;
        T result = null;
        for (; retryCount < MaxRetries; retryCount++)
        {
            try
            {
                result = DoSomethingWithRequest(request);
                if(result != null) break;
            }
            catch
            {
                //log here     
            }
            finally
            {
                request = func();    
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Now we have seen that when we have more than 10 lists in `ListOfLists` (so only 10 execute at any time and the rest wait) and `DoSomethingWithRequest` fails a few times intermittently, some of the calls to `SomeFunction` are duplicated and some of the lists of ids are dropped. Is there something in the code above that causes this?

Please excuse the not-so-descriptive title.

Thanks,
Sid.

Edit:

```
    private HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(HttpRequestType request, List<string> ids)
    {
        if (request == null) return null;
        request.SomeProperty = toList;
        return ConvertoToHttpRequestMessage(request); //This just does some serialization and adds a fresh request Id and headers
    }
```

Comment: What does `CreateRequest` do with the `HttpRequest` you're passing it? Can you post that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a race condition with the `request` instance that you pass to the `Execute` function.

```csharp
// The request instance must be created before this line, and you're passing the same
// instance to each call of Execute.
ListOfLists.Select(ids => Observable.FromAsync(() => Execute(request, ids))).Merge(10);
```

`CreateRequest` isn't creating a new instance of `HttpRequestType`, it's just modifying the one being passed to `Execute`. And since each thread `Execute` operates on the same instance of `HttpRequestType` they're simply overwriting each other.

So, something like the following may be happening:

`Thread A` starts, and the `ids` parameter is equal to `[1, 2, 3]`. `Thread A` enters `SomeFunction` and calls `func`. The `toList` parameter captured for `Thread A` is `[1, 2, 3]`, so `request.SomeProperty` gets set to `[1, 2, 3]` then an `HttpRequest` is created with `[1, 2, 3]` in a header somewhere and returned to `SomeFunction`. `DoSomethingWithRequestFails` for `Thread A`.

At the same time, `Thread B` has started. The `ids` parameter is equal to `[4, 5, 6]`. `Thread B` enters `SomeFunction` and calls `func`. `Thread B` sets `request.SomeProperty` to `[4, 5, 6]` then calls `ConvertToHttpRequestMessage`.

Now, before `Thread B` has a chance to create the `HttpRequest`, `Thread A` (which failed) enters the `finally` block in `SomeFunction` and calls `func` again. `Thread A` sets `request.SomeProperty` back to `[1, 2, 3]` and since `Thread A` and `Thread B` are both mutating the same `HttpRequestType` instance, `Thread B` now has `[1, 2, 3]` in `request.SomeProperty` as well.

Both `Thread A` and `Thread B` create an `HttpRequest` with `[1, 2, 3]` in the header. The list of ids `[1, 2, 3]` is duplicated and the list `[4, 5, 6]` is never sent.

Try passing the `toList` from `CreateRequest` to `ConvertToHttpRequestMessage` instead of just the `HttpRequestType`, or create a new instance of `HttpRequestType` for each call to `Execute`.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. That was my initial suspicion, but didn't want to make any big changes unless I was sure. Reading your response made me realise that it's actually the same `HttpRequestType` instance I'm passing around, so yeah, definitely a race condition there. I will try what you've suggested and let you know how we get on. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you start the parallel execution.

If you use `System.Parallel` you can send `ParallelOptions`. Here an Example call of `Parallel.ForEach()`

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

Parallel.ForEach(
    myList,
    new ParallelOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1337 // Here we allow 1337 parallel executions
    },
    (i) => { /* do something */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. `ListOfLists.Select(ids => Observable.FromAsync(() => Execute(request, ids)))` creates an observable sequence for each list and then they are `Merge`d. It's not so much running them in parallel that we're experiencing difficulty with. It's something that causes some of the retried `DoSomethingWithRequest` to get a wrong list passed. And all 3 bits above are in different classes used by other things as well, so want to keep the changes to a minimum.